# ActionController::Parameters duplicated key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following snippet is from one of my controllers:

```
Class Admin::Portfolios::PortfoliosController < Comfy::Admin::Cms::BaseControllers

  def create
    uploader = PortfolioUploader.new
    uploader.store!(params[:portfolio][:thumbnail])

    @portfolio.save!
    flash[:notice] = 'Portfolio item saved!'
    redirect_to :action => :index
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    flash.now[:error] = 'Error saving portfolio item'
    render :action => :new
  end
```

In development mode `params[:portfolio][:thumbnail]` is set in the controllers request params. However in production mode `params[:portfolio_portfolio][:thumbnail]` is set instead.

I'm using `form_for(@portfolio)` and in development all the form fields name are `portfolio[name]` and `portfolio_portfolio[name]` in production mode. See the erb below.

```
<%= form_for @portfolio, :url => {:action => :create}, :html => {:multipart => true} do |form| %>
    <% render :partial => form %>
<% end %>
```

Can anybody explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you post your haml, erb file?

Comment: @Dinesh added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with my application structure

```
app
├── controllers
├── helpers
├── mailers
├── models
│   ├── portfolio
│   │   └── portfolio.rb
│   ├── portfolio.rb
└──
```

`form_form` looks for an `:as` option to use as the form and field names. If no `:as` option is passed it will execute `model_name_from_record_or_class` which does what it says on the tin. The `portfolio.rb` class higher up in the model directory shouldn't have existed and was an empty class.

Because the `Portfolio` class was already defined the class `Portfolio::Portfolio` was transformed to `portfolio_portfolio`.